# akka unstashAll generate java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: akka

everyone. A have a unexpected error with akka unstashAll function.
in my actor it is a simple function that do context.become(idle())
than unstashAll()

```
private def becomeIdle(list: List[String]): Unit = {
  become(idle(list))
  setReceiveTimeout(Duration.Undefined)
  unstashAll()
}
```

and suddenly a see

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at akka.actor.StashSupport.$anonfun$unstashAll$2(Stash.scala:217)
at akka.actor.StashSupport.$anonfun$unstashAll$2$adapted(Stash.scala:217)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:502)
at akka.actor.StashSupport.unstashAll(Stash.scala:218)
at akka.actor.StashSupport.unstashAll$(Stash.scala:215)
at com.myapp.TestActor.unstashAll(TestActor.scala:23)
at akka.actor.StashSupport.unstashAll(Stash.scala:198)
at akka.actor.StashSupport.unstashAll$(Stash.scala:198)
at myapp.TestActor.unstashAll(myapp.TestActor.scala:23)
at com.myapp.TestActor.com$myapp$TestActor$becomeIdle(TestActor.scala:122)
at com.myapp.TestActor$$anonfun$awaitData$1.applyOrElse(TestActor.scala:87)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:513)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:511)
at com.myapp.TestActor.aroundReceive(TestActor.scala:23)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:519)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:488)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

i trace it in debugger

Stash.scala

```
198 def unstashAll(): Unit = unstashAll(_ ⇒ true)
```

then

```
215 private[akka] def unstashAll(filterPredicate: Any ⇒ Boolean): Unit = {
216   try {
217     val i = theStash.reverseIterator.filter(envelope ⇒ filterPredicate(envelope.message))
218     while (i.hasNext) enqueueFirst(i.next())
219   } finally {
220     theStash = Vector.empty[Envelope]
221   }
222 }
```

at string 218 i have "Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate scala.collection.iterator$$anon$12.toString()

and i state is

```
hd = null
hdDefined = false
$outer = {Vector$$anon$1@9153} "empty iterator"
  i = 0
$outer = {Vector@9133} "Vector" size = 1
  All elements are null
p = {StashSupport$lambda@11430} 
  arg = {StashSupport$lambda@9140} 
    Class has no fields

theStash = {Vector@9133} "Vector" size = 1
  All elements are null
```

Help me please!

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducer?

Comment: I just have an actor, where i do unstash All() when no stash() happened

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are doing something more, the following does not cause NPE for example: https://gist.github.com/johanandren/35bdebef9d3a084a8f7dc88070485767 are you perhaps on a very old Akka version? 2.5.1 is latest stable, and 2.4.18 is latest previous version, you should definitely not be on 2.3 any more as it has been end-of-lifed.